# Javascript : dealing with arrays into object (in angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following issue :

```
$scope.creneaux1=creneauxFactory.list();
console.log($scope.creneaux)
```

gives me what i expect :

```
Object {}
```

and inside the object

```
creneaux : Arrays[35]
inscriptions : Arrays[554]
```

etc..

Whenever i try to acess te inscriptions arrays with

```
console.log($scope.creneaux.inscriptions)
console.log($scope.creneaux.inscriptions[0])
console.log($scope.creneaux["inscriptions"])
```

I got undefined.

How can i do ?

Factory part thats is used therefore :

```
    var creneaux ={},
  urlphp = "http://bacly.fr/baclymphp/",
  phpFiles = {
        getCreneaux: "getCreneaux.php",
        getInscriptionsclub: "getInscriptionsclub.php",
        getUsers: "getUsers.php"
    },
    countResponse=0;

function getDate(from, onSuccess, onError) {

    $http.get(urlphp + from).then(function (response) {
        if (response) {
            if (onSuccess) {
                onSuccess(response)
            }
        } else if (onError) {
            onError()
        }
    }, function () {
        onError();
    }
    )
}
getDate(phpFiles.getCreneaux, function (response) {
    creneaux.creneaux = response.data;
    countResponse++;
}, function () {
    alert("pas d acces reseau");
});
getDate(phpFiles.getInscriptionsclub, function (response) {
    creneaux.inscriptions = response.data;
    countResponse++;
}, function () {
    alert("pas d acces reseau");
});
getDate(phpFiles.getUsers, function (response) {
    creneaux.users = response.data;
    countResponse++;
}, function () {
    alert("pas d acces reseau");
});


 return {
    getResponseAfterSuccess: function (onSuccess, onError) {  

        if (Object.keys(phpFiles).length == countResponse) {
            if (onSuccess) onSuccess(tournois);
        } else {
            if (onError) onError(tournois);
        }
    },    
    list: function(){
        return creneaux;
    },
    listinsc: function(){
        return creneaux.inscriptions;
    },        
    findcreneau: function(cid){
        return _.find(creneaux.creneaux, function(t) {return t.creneau_id === cid});
    },
    findinscription: function(cid){
        return _.filter(creneaux.inscriptions, function(t) {return t.inscriptions_uid == cid});
    },
```

UPDATE : i tried to improve my code but when i use for example :

```
        $scope.selectedinscription=creneauxFactory.findinscription(window.localStorage.getItem('logmbaclyuid'));
```

i get an empty array. How to proceed to wait for data to be available ?

Comment: `console.log($scope.creneaux[0]);`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$scope.creneaux.creneaux.inscriptions`?

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing the context where you are trying to do `console.log` in your code, and where your `$scope.creneaux` object is being populated with the two arrays. But seems to me like you are trying to do `console.log($scope.creneaux.inscriptions)` before it is available.

Comment: Could you share a little bit of more code?

Comment: @jannagy02 : i added more code. It comes from a factory method. i gave full code

Comment: It looks like `list()` returns an empty object initially, and that object is populated with `inscriptions` later after an AJAX call. It might be better to return a promise object so that you can wait for the list to be available before using it.

Comment: Just like I suspected, your object is only populated after the http requests return data. So you should try to use it only after it becomes available. Even if you can't see the variable when you do `console.log`, you will still be able to use them in the view and will be available when the responses are received.

Comment: @show-me-the-code : i tried to improve my code, still now get an empty array. How to proceed to wait for data to be available ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly wait until all your data has been received, and then fire a callback. Here's one way to do it.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testCtrl"> 
    <pre>
    {{selectedinscription|json}}
    </pre>
</div>
```

```js
// Factory
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.factory('dataFactory', function ($http) {
    var urlphp = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/",
        phpFiles = {
            getCreneaux: "posts",
            getInscriptionsclub: "albums",
            getUsers: "comments"
        },
        countResponse = 0;

    function getDate(from, onSuccess, onError) {

        $http.get(urlphp + from).then(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                if (onSuccess) {
                    onSuccess(response)
                }
            } else if (onError) {
                onError()
            }
        }, function () {
            onError();
        })
    }




    return {
        creneaux: {},
        init: function (callback) {
            var that = this;
            getDate(phpFiles.getCreneaux, function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                that.creneaux.creneaux = response.data;
                that.getResponseAfterSuccess(callback);
            }, function () {
                alert("pas d acces reseau");
            });
            getDate(phpFiles.getInscriptionsclub, function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                that.creneaux.inscriptions = response.data;
                that.getResponseAfterSuccess(callback);
            }, function () {
                alert("pas d acces reseau");
            });
            getDate(phpFiles.getUsers, function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                that.creneaux.users = response.data;
                that.getResponseAfterSuccess(callback);
            }, function () {
                alert("pas d acces reseau");
            });
        },
        getResponseAfterSuccess: function (callback) {
            if (_.keys(phpFiles).length === _.keys(this.creneaux).length) {
                callback();
            }
        },
        list: function () {
            return this.creneaux;
        },
        listinsc: function () {
            return this.creneaux.inscriptions;
        },
        findcreneau: function (cid) {
            return _.find(this.creneaux.creneaux, function (t) {
                return t.id === cid
            });
        },
        findinscription: function (cid) {
            console.log("Searching for " + cid);
            console.log(this.creneaux);
            return _.filter(this.creneaux.inscriptions, function (t) {
                return t.id == cid
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```js
// Controller
app.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope, dataFactory) {
    var onSuccess = function () {
        $scope.selectedinscription = dataFactory.findinscription(1);
    };

    dataFactory.init(onSuccess);

});
```

And here's a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybo4bvbj/). I have used generic REST APIs to pull data, but you get the point.

Comment: Thanks a lot m8, it works great and helped me understanding this concept !

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it was helpful. This will help future visitors find the right answer without having to go through all the posts and comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
creneaux : Arrays[35]
inscriptions : Arrays[554]
```

If this is inside $scope.creneaux, then the output means that creneaux holds another creneaux array, so you would access it like so:

```
console.log($scope.creneaux.creneaux[0])
```

Comment: creneaux contains 2 arrays :
creneaux and inscriptions.
i tried  console.log($scope.creneaux.creneaux[0]) => gives me undefined

Comment: could you show a bit of the code where you call the method of that service?